# Get last 5 record from log files

Tags: php, file

I have a folder **Userlog** which contains log file of each user separately. Now i want to search the entire log files for a particular text and get last 5 entries for that text.
On each log file date and time of line entry is available like

```
2017-10-05 15:43:32 pm--abcd--192.9.200.232--183--Select Date--NA--NA--Edit-05-10-2017
```

CODE:

```
function getUserLog($path_to_check, $search) 
{
    $result = array();

    foreach (glob($path_to_check . '*.txt') as $filename) {

          foreach (file($filename) as $lineNumber => $line) {

               if (strpos($line, $search) !== false) {

                   $fil_name= basename($filename,".txt");

                    $result[] = $line."--".$fil_name;  
                }
           }
    }

    return $result;

}
$path_to_check = "userlogs/";

if ( is_dir($path_to_check)) {
   $user_log = getUserLog($path_to_check,$cino);
}
```

Comment: Share your code..

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is store the name of the file as an array key (as long as the filenames are valid [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) keys) and then add the matched lines (ignoring the newline) to that array.
Finally add that array which has the filename as a key and your matched lines to your `$result`.

Then you could loop the `$user_log`, and take the last 5 from the `$matchedLines` using [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) and add that to a new array `$resultSliced`.

For example:

```
function getUserLog($path_to_check, $search)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach (glob($path_to_check . '*.txt') as $filename) {
        foreach (file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES) as $lineNumber => $line) {
            if (strpos($line, $search) !== false) {
                $fil_name = basename($filename, ".txt");
                $result[$fil_name][] = $line;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$resultSliced = [];
$path_to_check = "userlogs/";
if (is_dir($path_to_check)) {
    $user_log = getUserLog($path_to_check, $cino);
    foreach ($user_log as$fileName => $matchedLines) {
        $resultSliced[$fileName] = array_slice($matchedLines, -5, 5, true);
    }
}
```

Then your result would for example have a structure like:

```
Array
(
    [filename1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-10-05 15:43:32 pm--abcd--192.9.200.232--183--Select Date--NA--NA--Edit-05-10-2017 etc
        )

    [filename2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-10-05 15:43:32 pm--abcd--192.9.200.232--183--Select Date--NA--NA--Edit-05-10-2017 etc
            [1] => 2017-10-05 15:43:32 pm--abcd--192.9.200.232--183--Select Date--NA--NA--Edit-05-10-2017 etc
            [2] => 2017-10-05 15:43:32 pm--abcd--192.9.200.232--183--Select Date--NA--NA--Edit-05-10-2017 etc
            [3] => 2017-10-05 15:43:32 pm--abcd--192.9.200.232--183--Select Date--NA--NA--Edit-05-10-2017 etc
            [4] => 2017-10-05 15:43:32 pm--abcd--192.9.200.232--183--Select Date--NA--NA--Edit-05-10-2017 etc
```